# Discontinuous group of isometries on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is generated by 1 or 2 elements

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, isometry

I am trying to prove the following theorem :

> A discontinuous, fixed point free group G of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is generated by one or two elements.

We may find an outline of the demonstration [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Cao.pdf) although it only consider the case of the group containing only translations.

If $G$ contains only translations the theorem follows from the demonstration found in the link above. When G contains both glide reflections and translations Stillwell's hint is :

> If $G$ is a discontinuous,fixed point free group of glide reflections and translations,let **g** be a glide reflection of minimal lenght in $G$ and let **h** be an element of minimal lenght not in the direction of **g**. Show that **g**, **h** must have perpendicular directions (e.g. by finding shorter elements when the directions of **g** ,**h** are not perpendicular.

As in the previous case I tried to show that when **g** and **h** are not in perpendicular direction then I can find a $m\mathbb{Z}; |h^{-1}g^{m}(P)-P|<|h(P)-p|$ but having little information about this composition I got little success in this approach. Any hint is appreciated.

Definition 1: A fixed point free group of isometries is a group $G$ such that for all $g\in G-{e}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ we have $g(P)\neq P$. Here $e$ is the identity.

Definition 2: A glide reflection is the composition of a reflection in a line and a translation along that line.

Comment: Btw, is this Stillwell's Na\"ive Lie theory book?

Comment: It's Stillwell's Geometry of surfaces.

Comment: Hint: Consider $[g,h]$.

Comment: Why it is shorter when g and h are not perpendicular? I can't see that.

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien: Verify that $[g,h]$ is a rotation, never mind the "shorter" part.

Comment: What do you call "discontinuous"?

Comment: Fix a point x,then its orbit by the group action is at least $\epsilon$ away from x,in other words $d(x,gx)>\epsilon$, Right now it's better to show why the comutator mentioned by Moishe Cohen is not a translation,proving this is proving the theorem.Note that it has to be either a translation or rotation because its the composition of an even number of reflections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L: Isom(E^2)\to O(2)$ be the homomorphism given by taking linear parts of the affine maps. Suppose that $f, g\in Isom(E^2)$ are glide-reflections along non-perpendicular (and non-parallel lines). Then their linear parts $L(f), L(g)$ are reflections in non-perpendicular and distinct lines through the origin. It is a pleasant exercise to show that such $L(f), L(g)$ do not commute. Therefore,
$$
L([f,g])= [L(f), L(g)]\ne id.
$$ 
Hence, $[f,g]$ is a rotation.

Comment: The proof  was finished considering the lattice and using triangles but your solution and how it uses group theory is delightful.

Comment: This proof seems indeed very elegant. However, I have some issues understanding it, and I would like too to understand Stillwell's result:

- what about the case of g being a translation and not a glide reflection? (which does not seem to be considered by your answer)
- there is a part of the argument I do not get: $L([f, g])$ is not the identity, thus $[f, g]$ is not a translation. But why would it necessarily be a rotation?

Comment: @Amomentum: I will add more details later, but note that the commutator has to be orientation-preserving. Thus, it is either a translation or a rotation, there is nothing else.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking forward reading it. There are many details in the final argument (to get the general result, for instance not just assuming two glide reflections) I don't get, so that I think it was relevant to open a new thread to clarify the points I don't find here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598913/discontinuous-fixed-point-free-group-of-glide-reflections-and-translations

Comment: I also added a bounty to this new post for a canonical answer